# Is there any other way to implement the blockchain synchronization less time consuming?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

If we implement another way of synchronizing the blockchain, for example distribute it on several nodes and make groups of nodes handle the whole copy of blockchain instead of single nodes, (in order to reduce the time needed to synchronize the chain), does it make any harm to the integrity of the blockchain?

Comment: The idea you have, seems to me related more to the scalability of the ethereum network than the syncronization process, which is done only if you install a new client. Could that be?

Comment: It could be, yes, but also would solve the time issue. A divided blockchain (obviously) would have less blocks; resulting in faster synchronization. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most time of the syncronization is spend by verifying the integrity of the blocks. It is a security measure that you can circumvent partially if you start the syncronization with `geth --fast`

Comment: You are right, yet dividing the blockchain into smaller pieces could also be a solution to the time issue. Obviously less blocks result in less time needed to check them. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you have a free lunch at a chinese restaurant and they bring you small plates you will get as full as if you order an entire peking duck. So the division of blocks does not help, because its the amount of transactions that happened over time that makes the blockchain huge